# Filter and Hooks caused to re-render issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, tus

I have a file system that I am building with tus. So for each file upload, I will have an array with ReactElement which will kickstart the uploading process. Adding an element into the array has no issue, but what I faced is the issue of deleting the upload if say I uploaded a file and wish to remove it from the array. Using filter() will create a new array which cause my ReactElement to re-render = re-upload the folder. I have tried using splice method which doesn't work as well. Please advise.

```
const [files, addFile] = useState<JSX.Element>([]);
const startUpload = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    // some code here
    addFile([...files, <File/>]
    // <File delete={deleteUpload}/> contains the tus uploading process
}

const deleteUpload = (name: string): void => {
    // Using filter() method
    addFile(prevState => prevState.filter(file => file.name !== name))
    
    // Using splice
    let temp = [...files];
    for(let i=0; i<temp.length; i++){
        if(temp[i].name === name){
             temp.splice(i,1)
        }
    }
    addFile(temp)

    // Both filter() and splice() does not work as filter() cause my <File/> to
    // re-render within the array and splice() will delete everything below
}
```

// Further edit based on the comments
The `<File/>` looks similar to

```
const File = (props) => {
    useEffect(()=>{

    let uploadOptions: any = {
          endpoint: 'http://localhost:5000/files',
          chunkSize: 8 * 1024 * 1024,
          resume: true,
          retryDelays: [0, 3000, 5000, 10000, 20000],
          headers: {
            filename: file.name,
            filetype: file.type,
          },
          metadata: {
            filename: file.name,
            filetype: file.type,
          },
          onError(error: any) {
            console.log(`Failed because: ${error}`);
          },
          onProgress(bytesUploaded: number, bytesTotal: number) {
            const percentage = ((bytesUploaded / bytesTotal) * 100).toFixed(2);
            console.log(bytesUploaded, bytesTotal, percentage + "%")
      },
      onSuccess() {
        console.log("Download %s from %s", upload.file.name, upload.url)
      },
    };

        // Create a new tus upload
        upload = new tus.Upload(file, uploadOptions);
        upload.start() // starting the upload process the moment I drop a file in
    },[])

    return (<> some progress bars and stop buttons to stop pause upload </>)
}
```

Comment: Can you give us more context? Why re-rendering will cause re-uploading the files?

Comment: what about adding a status to each file ,whether it still exists or is deleted, and applying the filter in your uploading function, (maybe without updating the state).
Also, as in the above comment, more context that explains why the re-rending causes re-uploading would be helpful

Comment: Please show more of your code in this component, especially the code related to how the upload process is triggered.

Comment: How are you triggering the upload? If it's on every render, then *that* is the issue. Make it only trigger on mount

Comment: @all Thank you for your response, Please refer to my edited question on the ```<File/>``` basically upload adding a file, it will trigger a useEffect() and automatically starts an upload.

Comment: I don't understand your approach, I would trigger the file upload on some event, like `onChange` on some file input.

Comment: Oh it's not re-rendering, it's re-mounting. there's nothing to uniquely identify the files in the array between re-renders in the parent. The best solution for this would to be take components out of the state (you shouldn't really store components in state anyway) and just store their IDs in the state. Then when rendering, loop through and render a `<File/>` for each ID, using the ID as the key. That way you can add or remove them and they won't remount, and you can find them easily enough via their ID

Comment: @Camilo, so the reason is I would like to have a base component, with each sub-component being the individual files so I can handle multi-file upload, and to choose which files I want to pause / resume / abort / delete the upload. I'm looking it similar to a to-do list where you can add task but each task with more features hence moving each task into a sub-component

Comment: whay are you adding the component itself to the state and not just the data?

Comment: I recently added Tus support to [react-uploady](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rpldy/tus-uploady). I can tell you that its a lot of work and there are a lot of cases and edge-cases to consider. Unless you're building this for the  fun of it, I'd really recommend using a library like mine to handle all the logic for you.